# Sitronix ST9RM01 touchscreen not working

Tags: multi-touch, touchscreen

I have a Sitronix ST9RM01 touchscreen that I'm trying to get working with Ubuntu 12.04.

The touchscreen is apparently recognized by Linux and X - the `hid_multitouch` module is loaded, and `lsinput` and `xinput` both list the touchscreen as an input device - but touching the screen does absolutely nothing, and `xinput test` shows no events.

The same touchscreen works just fine in Windows.

How can I troubleshoot from here?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From talking with one of the hid-multitouch developers, the following will commands will work around this problem in Ubuntu 12.10:

```
sudo su
echo 16 > /sys/module/hid_multitouch/drivers/hid\:hid-multitouch/0003\:1403\:5001.*/quirks
```

A future kernel update will fix things so that this will no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-ubuntu-howto.html

Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-multitouch

sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-multitouch.conf
```

then replace driver `multitouch` by driver `hid-multitouch`

Reboot and it should work.